# Backbonejs & underscroejs with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I was learning backbonejs and trying to use along with my Spring MVC web application.

The Spring MVC application is configured perfect and there are no errors within it. But issue I am facing is with underscore template which is part of my jsp file.

> **index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome To Demo</h1>
        <div id="todo">
        </div>
        <script type="text/template" id="item-template">
            <div class="view">
                <input id="todo_complete" type="checkbox" {{ completed ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} />
                <label>{{ title }}</label>
                <button class="destroy"></button>
            </div>
            <input class="edit" value="{{ title }}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"/>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/underscore.js"/>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/backbone-min.js"/>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/views/js/custom/demo.js"/>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that for binding I'm using symbol

> {{}} rather than <%= %>

for that I have modified my underscore js file:

> **underscore.js**

```
_.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
    };
```

I can see when I receive index.jsp in a browser, the code of template is unresolved:

[image: firebug screenshot]

The backbone code I've kept in a separte JS file called

> **demo.js**

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: '',
        completed: false
    }
});

var myTodo = new Todo({
    title: 'Check attributes property of the logged models in the console.'
});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName:  'li',
  todoTpl: _.template( $('#item-template').html() ),
  events: {
    'dblclick label': 'edit',
    'keypress .edit': 'updateOnEnter',
    'blur .edit':   'close'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.$el = $('#todo');

  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.todoTpl( this.model.attributes ) );

    this.input = this.$('.edit');
    return this;
  },
  edit: function() {

  },
  close: function() {

  },
  updateOnEnter: function( e ) {

  }
});

var todoView = new TodoView({model: myTodo});
```

So final output looks like

[image: nothing except welcome to demo]

Do let me know if you want any other info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to add

```
todoView.render();
```

Also let us know whether all those scripts are resolved properly after browser loads `index.jsp`. I mean are js script links accessible?